# ColdFusion encrypt is returning same encryption for different values

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm using ColdFusion 9 in a web application I'm working on.

We've run into some issues with encryption. First we were getting the "The input and output encodings are not same." error,

We are using the CFMX_COMPAT algorithm. The key is pretty long and not a simple one.

When testing some encrypted values to see if they had anything special, i tried the 2 following numbers:

- 37144963539843
- 37144963539842 (only difference is the last digit)

Surprised, i got the same encrypted value back.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you checked the encrypted results? Dumping them on screen? Where are you storing encrypted values?

Comment: I am calling the method with c#. For testing i'm hitting the method directly through the browser and it's displayed on the page. The encrypted values are stored in a mssql database as a varchar(200)

Comment: I just ran a test case and it came alright. You will like to check the last character of the encrypted values which should be the only difference between them them, rest being the same.

Comment: When I used a different key, the result was like you mentioned. However, using the current key, for some reason, I'm definitely getting back the same values. I might be able to use a different key, but i'm not sure what's causing this so i don't have a way to make sure it doesn't happen with other values.  EDIT: If I add a '1' to both numbers, I again get back the same values.

Comment: Do you mind providing the key you are using? I used various combination key and result is always expected. I will like to add that cfmx_compat is poorest encryption mechanism.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a live site with real credit cards so i can't share the key. Regarding it being unsafe, we are moving away from coldfusion so it won't be used for much longer but I appreciate the comment.

Comment: No worries. I understand. Then you would be better changing your Key. I am 100% sure though that however poor this encryption method is, but it works the way it is designed to. And same results could be a typo or whatever a silly mistake everyone including I have made many times too. Good Luck.

Comment: `cfmx_compat` should **never be used for storing credit cards**! It is not encryption at all. It is little more than a poor obfuscation algorithm. ColdFusion supports real encryption algorithms such as RSA, AES, etcetera so there is no reason to be using `cfmx_compat`.

Comment: You were right. They looked the same in my browser because the browser removed some of the whitespace and other characters that were different.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Leigh, I agree with your comment. I didn't write the original code and at this point, the client decides what's important for them. I'll make sure to make it more secure when we move away from CF.

Comment: @edank - Ask them if *having* customers, and not getting fined or sued, is important to them. It could easily be done in CF right now. Almost certainly, with less code than the C# equivalent. Leaving things this way - when they could easily be made more secure - just seems very irresponsible of them. Makes me want to ask which company so I never do business with them.. Wonder if they are storing *their* credit cards in this system.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing values in the browser, which removed important characters (e.g whitespace).

ugh.